# Thread hanging issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am studying how C# handles threads and events. In order to do so, I wrote a simple program that simulates a thermometer and a three axes encoder (at the moment everything is just random generated data). I then wrote some events that: start generation/reading of the encoder and the thermometer, write in a listbox a string if the temperature goes over a threshold, log the temperature data in a logfile, with different strings based on temperature values.

In order to do so, I wrote 4 different classes, here they are:

1st: The windows form class, Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Sensors;

namespace TestWindowsFormsApp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Termometer termometro;
    private AxisPosition assi;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        termometro = new Termometer();
        termometro.HighTemperatureReached += Termometro_HighTemperatureReached;
        new TemperatureLogger(termometro); 
        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing; 
        assi = new AxisPosition();
        assi.PositionRead += Assi_PositionRead;
    }

    private void Assi_PositionRead(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        XValue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            XValue.Text = $"{x}";
            YValue.Text = $"{y}";
            ZValue.Text = $"{z}";
        });
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        termometro.HighTemperatureReached -= Termometro_HighTemperatureReached;
        assi.PositionRead -= Assi_PositionRead;
        termometro.StopReading();
        assi.StopReading();
    }

    private void Termometro_HighTemperatureReached(int value)
    {
        AlertsListBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            AlertsListBox.Items.Add($"Temperatura alta, {value} °C");
        });
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            termometro.StartReading();       
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exeption)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exeption.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AxisResetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: IMPLEMENT
    }

    private void AxisReadStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            assi.StartReading();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exeption)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exeption.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

2nd: The temperature logger class, TemperatureLogger.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Sensors;

namespace TestWindowsFormsApp
{
public class TemperatureLogger
{
    public TemperatureLogger(Termometer termometro)
    {
        termometro.TemperatureRead += Termometro_TemperatureRead;
        termometro.HighTemperatureReached += Termometro_HighTemperatureReached;
    }

    private void Termometro_HighTemperatureReached(int value)
    {

        File.AppendAllText("temperature.log", $"{DateTime.Now} - !!!WARNING!!! Temperature read: {value} °C\n");
    }

    private void Termometro_TemperatureRead(int value)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("temperature.log", $"{DateTime.Now} - Temperature read: {value} °C\n");
    }
}
}
```

3rd: the Axes position class, AxisPosition.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sensors
{
    public class AxisPosition
    {
        private Thread readingThread;
        private bool isReading = false;
        public delegate void AxisNotification(int x, int y, int z);
        public event AxisNotification PositionRead;
        public event AxisNotification PositionSet;
        private int x_ref = 0;
        private int y_ref = 0;
        private int z_ref = 0;

        public void StartReading()
        {
            if (readingThread != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Positioner is already reading!");

            readingThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (isReading)
                {
                    var x = new Random().Next(1000) - x_ref;
                    var y = new Random().Next(300) - y_ref;
                    var z = new Random().Next(600) - z_ref;

                    if (PositionRead != null)
                        PositionRead(x, y, z);

                    if (PositionSet != null)
                        PositionSet(x, y, z);

                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Exit from axes Thread.");
            });

            isReading = true;
            readingThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
            readingThread.Start();

        }


        public void StopReading()
        {

            isReading = false;
            if (readingThread != null)
            {
                int watchdog = 0;
                while (readingThread.IsAlive && watchdog <= 50)
                {
                    watchdog++;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                readingThread = null;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

And, finally, the 4th class, the one reading temperature, Termometer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sensors
{
    public class Termometer
    {

        private Thread readingThread;
        public void StartReading()
        {

            if (readingThread != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Termometer is already reading!");

            readingThread = new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    var read = new Random().Next(100);

                                    if (read > 50 && HighTemperatureReached != null)
                                        HighTemperatureReached(read);

                                    if (TemperatureRead != null)
                                        TemperatureRead(read);

                                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (ThreadAbortException) {
                                // Clean up
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("Esco dal Thread di lettura temperature.");
                        }
                       );

            readingThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
            readingThread.Start();

        }
        public event TemperatureNotificationDelegate HighTemperatureReached;
        public event TemperatureNotificationDelegate TemperatureRead;    

        public void StopReading()
        {
            if (readingThread != null)
            {
                readingThread.Abort();
                readingThread = null;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I have a problem while I close the form windows: sometimes (it seems random) some thread remains hanging, and I have to close manually (hence the Abort() method). This is a bruteforce workaround, but I would prefer to make the thread exit gracefully, as I did in the axes one. 
My question is: why sometimes the thread doesn't exit, but remains hanging?

It seems by doind some debug that the condition isreagind == false doesn't get elaborated correctly, but I can't understand why.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: where is it getting stuck?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578695/set-thread-as-background-or-not

Comment: When you close the form window. Basically, the event isClosing is called, the thread running condition is set to false and it should close gracefully. This sometimes does not happen. and the application stay hunged. I found a turnaround by using the Thread.Abort() method, but I would like to know what is happen, in order to prevent such behaviour in production stage.

Comment: XValue.Invoke() is a deadlock waiting to happen.  If it occurs just as your UI thread is calling StopReading() then you will have a problem.  Always favor BeginInvoke().  Not the only issue, a *bool* like isReading is not a synchronization object, the worker thread might never see it turning false.  There is no obvious reason why threads are useful here, all they do is sleep.  Consider simple Timers instead, the one you find in the toolbox.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However I have a few question:
Why it is a deadlock? If I understand how things work, those methods just invoke the update of the form GUI, so even if the form doesn't exist anymore, they should close with an exception and not remain hanging... Am I right?
Also, how could the bool value fail? As long as the gui exists it should work... Could you kindly explain?
I understand that using threads here is.. Not optimal, but this was a practice application for both events and threads.